# Why isn't superuser.stackexchange.com redirected to superuser.com?

Tags: discussion

Some of the SE sites I visit have domain names of the form [site].stackexchange.com and some [site].com.  Since I hardly ever use links and type a few chars in the URL bar to get to a site this sometimes tangles me up.

Does anyone else see any value in this or am I just too lazy and easily confused? :)

Edit: Changed angle brackets to square so they would show up.

Comment: I just had this happen for the Nth time, but this is the first time I actually realized that the domain is superuser.com with no reference to stackexchange at all... I guess in the past I googled it and didn't read, just clicked.

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard this request before, and I don't agree with it.

Besides, `superuser.stackexchange.com` makes no sense as a topic division, compare to `apple.stackexchange.com` and `wordpress.stackexchange.com` and `cooking.stackexchange.com`

Comment: I actually tried to get to 'superuser.stackexchange.com' tonight.  From a consistency viewpoint, it would be good if all the stackexchange-run sites (everything listed at http://stackexchange.com/sites) had a sitename.stackexchange.com URL: if I know the site's name and I know it's hosted by stackexchange, I would like to be able to type 'sitename.stackexchange.com' and get to it (actually this is probably properly a question for ui.stackexchange.com ;)).

Comment: @drewbenn: I like the consistency as well...  Sosueme. :)

Comment: computers.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Strict adherence to topic divisions might hamper usability in this case. I too just made the same mistake as drewbenn, but in my case I typed superuser.stackexchange.com into a message, sent it, then tested it and had to send a follow-up with the correct domain. Consistency is a valuable trait, but what we have here is a conflict between two types.

Comment: I don't understand the Answer given by Jeff. How does the name of the site not make sense as a topic division? Every other site that I know of is named xxxxxx.stackexchange.com, right? What makes SuperUser special that I should remember a different rule for it?