# Why doesn't Superuser have superuser.stackexchange.com address unlike other stackexchange websites?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange, meta

Similar to Stackoveflow, Superuser has independent domain. Is this because Superuser was older than most of the StackExchange sites before the StackExchange idea did come up?

What's the relation between two?

Comment: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/the-stack-overflow-trilogy/

Comment: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2052/why-isnt-superuser-stackexchange-com-redirected-to-superuser-com

Comment: Interestingly, arqade.com exists, but just redirects to gaming.SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Superuser's [one of the 'original' StackExchange sites](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/the-stack-overflow-trilogy/), AKA the trilogy - we predate the foo.stackexchange.com sites, [which I believe started with SE 2.0](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/)

So yeah, we're older and as such have a cool domain name.

Comment: *"In other words, things are going to get a little .. crazy .. in the finale."* - sums us up really

Comment: thankfully, no special editions, or prequels

Comment: later they didn't introduce alternate domain superuser.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Nope. They didn't do it for SF either